# ASP.NET MVC - How to execute conditional C# Code in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

First of all I am not a MVC developer - I am just trying to help out a few MVC guys in their project due to various constraints they have, so if this is a n00b thing, please don't shoot :)

Here is the thing - there is a framework that is used by this team which has a render function like so:

```
ObjMP.render ({
// various configuration options
   labels: [
 { settings: '@Html.Raw(lablesPosition[0])', content: '@Html.Raw(lablesContent[0])' },
 { settings: '@Html.Raw(lablesPosition[1])', content: '@Html.Raw(lablesContent[1])' }
 ]
```

The configuration option that is troubling me is the "labels" option shown above. 
"lablesContent" and "lablesPosition" are actually IList in my .cshtml file.

The above code uses settings stored in the collection at index 0 and 1 as you can see. This is actually a hard-coded thing.

I am not guaranteed that there will be only 2 items in the collection.

To overcome this I can do either :

1> Write a foreach loop somehow where instead of using lablesPosition[0] etc I can do something like lablesPosition[i]

2> I know the count of records in the collection for each scenario and so based on the scenario selection I write 5 settings or 4 settings using an if - else block like so :

```
if(selectiong=="a")
{
labels: [
 { settings: '@Html.Raw(lablesPosition[0])', content: '@Html.Raw(lablesContent[0])' },
 { settings: '@Html.Raw(lablesPosition[1])', content: '@Html.Raw(lablesContent[1])' }
 ]
}

else if(Select=="b")
{
labels: [
 { settings: '@Html.Raw(lablesPosition[0])', content: '@Html.Raw(lablesContent[0])' },
 { settings: '@Html.Raw(lablesPosition[1])', content: '@Html.Raw(lablesContent[1])' },
{ settings: '@Html.Raw(lablesPosition[2])', content: '@Html.Raw(lablesContent[2])' }
 ]
}
```

The problem in second approach is that when the page is rendered the RAZOR engine seems to evaluate all the expression with "@" at run time regardless of the if - else condition valdiation in JS and hence the code breaks for me - basically it might try to access a value in the collection at position 6 when the collection has only 2 items.

How can I solve this problem ? 
(ASP.NET MVC 3)

Comment: Use the `foreach`/`for` loop intead of manually indexing items.

Comment: I'm slightly confused, you want to implement a specific java-script routine in C#. You want to change the JavaScript function based on whats available in your C# code?
The real question is, What do you want to happen to the extra JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question, your problem is that RAZOR can not know which C# values to skip based on Javascript. It does not evaluate the JS, it's just generating it.

It think you need to bring your conditional to the server level, if your logic supports that (and it should).

That means, the `if(selectiong=="a")` should not be a **JS** `if/else` it should be a **C#** `if/else`.

Take a look at this SO [question (Simple If/Else Razor Syntax)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710431/simple-if-else-razor-syntax) for a basic implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the pointers. In the end, I figured out a way of generating the data for "labels" in C# code dynamically and sending it to my JS in a variable which is evaluated as @Html.Raw in the config options and it works fine.